# Referencing external files with a node.js server?

Tags: resources, node.js

I have an Ubuntu 10.04 hosting server which allows me to run [node.js](http://nodejs.org) off of it.  I'm making an test homepage and I have a few files as follows:

`index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>iSuperMario</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/nowjs/now.js"></script>
    <script src="js/chat.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header">
            <img src="images/green_pipe_960.png">
            <img src="images/orange_pipe_960.png">
        </div>
        <div id="chat">
            <input type="text" id="text-input">
            <input type="button" value="Send" id="send-button">
        </div>
        <div id="content">
        </div>
        <div id="rooms">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

`reset.css` and `style.css` (which both just contain styling for the `index.html` page

`chat.js` (which contains some scripting to implement the barebones chat function for the `index.html` page)

`server.js` which is a `node.js` server utilizing [nowjs](http://nowjs.com/) to serve the `index.html` page on port `8080` of the Ubuntu server and to implement the chat function:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var server = require('http').createServer(function(req, response){
  fs.readFile(__dirname+'/index.html', function(err, data){
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'text/html'});
    response.write(data);
    response.end();
  });
});
server.listen(8080);
var everyone = require("now").initialize(server);


everyone.connected(function(){
  console.log("Someone has joined!");
});


everyone.disconnected(function(){
  console.log("Someone has left...");
});

everyone.now.distributeMessage = function(message){everyone.now.receiveMessage(message);};
```

So, when I view the page from the server in a browser, none of the external resources (`reset.css`, `style.css`, `chat.js`, `green_pipe_960.png` and `orange_pipe_960.png`) are connected properly.

How should I enable these?  I mean, if I had to, and it simplified the process a great deal, I could always include the external styles and scripts in `index.html`.  But, the images could never be embedded (at least I think xD).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set your file structure as follows

```
 = main
   = index.html
   = css
     = reset.css
     = style.css
   = js
     = chat.js
   = images
     = green_pipe..
     = orange_pipe..
```

Alternatively you can change your urls to match your real file structure.

I would like to recommend you use `express` or something else if you want to server something beyond a very basic prototype.

Comment: I've tried using `express` but I don't know how to achieve this in `express` either...I'm assuming this makes the process simpler?

Comment: @BOSS in express you just make sure to point the files to the correct place. so "/css/foo.css" for the css file in public/css

Comment: So is it essentially the same as local?  In other words, I wouldn't have to change anything?

Comment: @BOSS you would. Theres a difference between "css/foo" and "/css/foo" one says from here go into css -> foo the other says from root go into css -> foo.

Comment: @boss `express --css less --sessions --template ejs` in shell. then just stick to their conventions.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about that that nice feature.  Thanks for helping out with so much thus far!

Comment: @BOSS Let me recommend [node.js SO chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/642/node-js) for simple questions and general discussion.

Comment: Wow, I never new stackoverflow had a chat web app (which loos very nice, actually)!  Thanks.

Comment: @zach: did you get to know how to load those external javascript files?
And the reason it does not load is because of this line in server.js

Answer (score 0):

This webpage might help. [Serving Static Files from Node.js](http://www.thecodinghumanist.com/blog/archives/2011/5/6/serving-static-files-from-node-js).